# Laravel - How to restrict certain functionality based on user authentication?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel newbie here (obviously :D ). I've set up a new model & controller for a model named `Pages`.

Every `User` has many `Pages`.

Each `Page` has a single `User`.

I've created the following functioning controller actions (& views):

```
PagesController::index
PagesController::create
PagesController::store
PagesController::show
PagesController::edit
PagesController::delete
```

So you can edit a `Page` by going to `url.dev/pages/{id}/edit`.

The problem is, you can access all of these routes regardless of your session status. So random users can edit any given `Page`. Which, obviously, is terrible.

**Can anyone point me in the direction of what I should read up on, to limit the ability to access my model's controller actions based on whether or not the user is logged in (and if it's the *correct* user, at all)?**

Answer (score 1):

You´re looking for middleware..
You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->only('index');

    $this->middleware('admin')->except('store');
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it had to be a thing I just haven't run across yet. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

To force a specific route to be only accessible by authenticated users you can specify middleware auth in the controller constructor, like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Also you can restrict which methods you want auth to be applied to in the controller, using the `only` or `except` parameters. Using only you could do:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['create', 'store', 'edit', 'delete']]);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now if I wanted to only restrict a few controller actions and not all of them, would I just try this in the ones I DO want restricted?

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are good, but I prefer to use middleware on route groups.

So when I have several routes like this:

```
Route::get('pages', 'PagesController@index')->name('pages.index');

Route::get('pages/{id}/edit', 'PagesController@edit')->name('pages.edit');
```

I would add them inside Laravel Route group. Like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('pages', 'PagesController@index')->name('pages.index');

    Route::get('pages/{id}/edit', 'PagesController@edit')->name('pages.edit');
});
```